# ReactJS display two arrays with mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays. The i'th element from both arrays form one component. I want to render multiple components like this in a list. Here's the code

```
var ShowData = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            var itemNames = this.props.names.map(function(item){
                return <div>{item}</div>;
            });
            var itemDesc = this.props.contents.map(function(description){
                return <p>{description}</p>;
            });

            return(
                <div>
                <h3> {itemNames}</h3>
                <div>{itemDesc}</div>
                </div>
                )

        }

    });
```

Here's my render function

```
<ShowData names = {this.state.items} contents = {this.state.desc} />
```

It displays the entire first array and then the entire second array. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arrays have the same order can you do it like this(Not tested).

```
var ShowData = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        var self = this;
        var items = this.props.names.map(function(item, key){
            return (<div>
                         <h3>{item}</h3> 
                         <div>{self.props.contents[key]}</div>
                    </div>);
        });
        return(
            <div>
                 {items}
            </div>
            )

    }

});
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer that passing two pieces of clearly related data like `item` and `description` as separate arrays is kind of terrible.  They should be passed to the component as an array of `{item: x, description: y}` elements instead.  Two arrays and indexing like this is just asking for trouble if they ever end up not being exactly equal lists with the correct corresponding indexes between the two.

Comment: @MikeDriver you are right.. and should tell this to the question author

Comment: @MikeDriver I realised that after I got my code working thanks to Jonatan. Now changed it to a single JSON object. Thanks guys !